# A .py file encrypted as Bytecode - how to do, how to read?

Tags: python, bytecode

While trying to make add-ons for some software, I stumbled upon .py files that looked like this:

```
BYTECODE(271)YwAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAEAAAABzVAAAAGQAAGQBAGwAAFRkAABkAQBsAQBUZQIAgwAAWgMAZAIAhAAAWgQAZAMAhAAAWgUAZQYAYQcAZAQAhAAAWggAZQMAagkAWgoAZQgAZQoAXwsAZAUAUygGAAAAaf////8oAQAAAHQBAAAAKmMCAAAACAAAAAUAAABDAAAAc0EBAAB0AABqAQBkAQCDAQB9AgB8AgBzGQB0AgBTfAIAagMAdAQAZAIAgwIAfQMAdAUAfAMAXwYAfA
```

(and so on; every file starts with BYTECODE(271)YwAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAEAAAABz).

Didn't know one could encrypt Python files in such a manner. So the questions are:

1. What tool did they use to get the byte code? How does Python interpret it anyway?
2. Any hope of making this readable? uncompyle6 didn't work.

Comment: From where did these came ? It depends on the source!

Comment: My guess is that this is a base64-encoded compiled python script of some sort. I'll fiddle with it and see if I can extract any data.

Comment: This doesn't even run on my laptop, actually. How did you run it?